# Spring RESTtemplate POST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am using the Spring Framework and trying to do a post request.  My post method takes the url, the HttpMethod, and the parameters that go into the body of the request.

NOTE: The var URL passed in network.POSTRequest( URL, ..,...) is different for each call.

Now, if I call this method with one parameter like so...(it works beautifully!)

```
//with one parameter
MultiValueMap<String, String> postParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
postParams.add("id", "524cd432539ed");
network.POSTRequest( URL, HttpMethod.POST, postParams );
```

,but if there are two parameters like so....(it throws this error)

*org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error*

```
//with two parameters
MultiValueMap<String, String> postParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
postParams.add("id", "crisp");
postParams.add("name", "honey");
network.POSTRequest( URL, HttpMethod.POST, postParams );
```

This is the POSTRequest method

```
public Object POSTRequest( String URL, HttpMethod method, MultiValueMap<String, String> postParams ){
            HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = 
                new HttpEntity< MultiValueMap<String, String> >(postParams, getHeaders());
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        List< HttpMessageConverter<?> > messageConverters = new ArrayList< HttpMessageConverter<?> >();

        messageConverters.add( new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter() );
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters( messageConverters );

        System.out.println( requestEntity.toString() );
        ResponseEntity result = 
                restTemplate.exchange( URL, method, requestEntity, APIResponse.class ) ;
        return result.getBody();
    }
```

Comment: Let's see your contoller

Comment: Have you tested the POST endpoint manually with a browser POST plugin or `wget`or `curl` using a single or multiple params? It could be the endpoint is barfing on 2 params.

Comment: yes, i have done a request using postman(chrome extension) and it is successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good way of setting message converters:

```
List< HttpMessageConverter<?> > messageConverters = new ArrayList< HttpMessageConverter<?> >();   
// empty list created

messageConverters.add( new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter() );   
// list has 1 elem now

restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());  
// adds StringHttpMessageConverter to restTemplate converter list

restTemplate.setMessageConverters( messageConverters );
// replaces restTemplate converter list with your custom list containing MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter only
// original list containing StringHttpMessageConverter is LOST
```

You should rather use consistent approach to this:

```
List< HttpMessageConverter<?> > messageConverters = new ArrayList< HttpMessageConverter<?> >();   
// empty list created

messageConverters.add( new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter() );      
messageConverters.add( new StringHttpMessageConverter() );  

restTemplate.setMessageConverters( messageConverters );
```

Comment: this isn't the solution, but definitely helpful advice.

Comment: i found out the problem.  It is not whether the request has one or two params.  The fact is that the api calls are different.  One api call accepts arrays and the other does not.  This is the main problem.